# ANSIBLE:: Could not resolve the syntax in the following yaml file

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am learning ansible and this is my YAML file.

```
---# Outline to playbook translation
- hosts: node1
  user: test
  sudo: yes
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: date time stamp at start
    raw: /usr/bin/date > /home/test/playbook_start.log
  - name:  install apache web server
    yum: pkg=httpd state=latest
  - name: start the service
    service: name=httd state=restarted
  - name: verify web service is running or not
    command: systemctl status httpd
    register: result
  - debug: var-result
  - name: install client SW telnet
    yum: pkg=telnet state=latest
  - name: install client pkg VIM
    yum: pkg=vim state=latest
```

and I get this error while running

```
 ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/home/test/Outline/webserver.yml': line 2, column 8, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---# Outline to playbook translation
- hosts: node1
       ^ here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this file:

```
---
# Outline to playbook translation
- hosts: node1
  user: test
  sudo: yes
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: date time stamp at start
    raw: /usr/bin/date > /home/test/playbook_start.log
  - name:  install apache web server
    yum: pkg=httpd state=latest
  - name: start the service
    service: name=httd state=restarted
  - name: verify web service is running or not
    command: systemctl status httpd
    register: result
  - debug: var=result
  - name: install client SW telnet
    yum: pkg=telnet state=latest
  - name: install client pkg VIM
    yum: pkg=vim state=latest
```

Comment: Your right, I removed this line from my response (and I fixed the text in my profile).

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is because you did not [separate the comment](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2780069) on the first line of the file from the preceding token (the *directives end marker*: `---`):

> Comments must be separated from other tokens by white space characters.

try:

```
--- # Outline to playbook translation
```

Answer (score 0):

Either remove "# Outline to playbook translation" or put it in a next line or give a space after ---